# Unknown option leads to error with babel and geometry

Tags: babel, geometry, package-options, class-options, options

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[logo height = 2\baselineskip]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
Text in case of empty.
\end{document}
```

I am getting errors like

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
\baselineskip 

Use of ??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> ???
```

which, according to the log file, seem to be reported by the packages `babel` and `geometry` (I haven't find other packages having the same issue).

Since class option is passed to every package, I would expect these packages to ignore unknown options. Is there thus some way to fix this current behavior to avoid errors?

Comment: I could imagine that it have to do with the option being a key-value argument which furthermore includes white spaces and an expandable macro. `geometry` as well as `babel` can also process key-value arguments, but maybe there is a conflict in the syntax or passing the key-value pair correctly.

Comment: Short answer: I don't think so. `babel` and `geometry` parse options in their own way, and they don't like things like `\baselineskip`. (@lukeflo That's no expandable macro; if it were, there would be no problem.) I don't see how to avoid the issue without heavily rewriting those packages' code of the kernel. But someone smarter than me might.

Comment: `babel` assumes options are valid names in `\DeclareOption`, and your option it’s not. Maybe some kind of ‘protection’ is required to avoid errors like this.

Comment: @JavierBezos hard to do protection here. One could use `logo height = \ifincsname\the\dimexpr2\baselineskip\relax\else2\baselineskip\fi`, but then this wouldn't survive the `\edef`-assignment of the global option list that most packages still use, so you'd need to protect against that as well.

Comment: @Skillmon This is why I quoted ‘protection’. Actually, I’m thinking of some kind of `\string`’ization (eg, with `\meaning`), but I have to be sure the result is not used in comparisons (the catcodes, you know).

Comment: @JavierBezos I'm not sure how `babel` has implemented options (I remember taking a look in the past, but found the whole option handling quite convoluted, and I don't remember the details). Maybe one can simply `\detokenize` the values.